Web Scraping for getting data with Python NoneType ERROR
I'm trying to get dollar, prices for my school project. So I decide to use web scraping for this but I have a problem about it. When I try to use my code on server it gives me NoneType ERROR. It works on google colab but I can't use on my pc or server. How can I solve this guys?
Web Scrape code ;
def dolar():
  headers = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.2 Safari/605.1.15'
  url = f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TRY=X/'
  r = requests.get(url)
  soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
  dolar = soup.find("div", {"class": "container yf-mgkamr"}).find_all("span")[0].text
  return dolar

EROOR ;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/API/main.py", line 38, in <module>
    dolar()
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/API/main.py", line 35, in dolar
    dolar = soup.find("div", {"class": "container yf-mgkamr"}).find_all("span")[0].text
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
(.venv) user@192 API % 

I tried to change my main website, tried to use without ".find_all" method. It doesn't change anything.

You should probably use this
import requests
import time


def dolar():
    now = time.time() - 10
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.2 Safari/605.1.15"
    }
    url = f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/TRY=X?period1={int(now)}&period2={int(now)}"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return response.json()['chart']['result'][0]['meta']['regularMarketPrice']


print(dolar())


how can I get this query1 link? is it a special method?

in inspect mode - Network

It's because soup.find("div", {"class": "container yf-mgkamr"}) is returning None. If you can share the HTML you are parsing, that would be helpful. But it's finding no div elements with a class="container yf-mgkamr".

This approach will not work. First I will demonstrate why, and then I will write a solution.
#! /usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from structlog import get_logger

logger = get_logger()

def dolar()->str:
    headers:str = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.2 Safari/605.1.15'
    url    :str = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TRY=X/'
    r           = requests.get(url)
    soup        = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    _div        = soup.find("div", {"class": "container yf-mgkamr"})
    try:
        _spans  = _div.find_all("span") # listen to Psilocybin
    except AttributeError as error:     # this error is always thrown
        logger.error(error)             # inform the user that it didn't work
        return r.text                   # show the user why it didn't work
    _span       = _spans[0]
    dolar  :str = _span.text
    return dolar
result:str = dolar()
logger.debug(result)

You can run (y)our code without grep to see that the HTML does not have the data you are expecting.
./so.py|grep -ie span -e div -q || echo no spans or divs found
no spans or divs found

Ok now let's get that data for you.

I copied a login script, deleted all the cool stuff, and dropped in the xpath from the image. For your convenience.
    async def run()->Optional[str]:
        _url             :str             = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TRY=X/'
        mean_arrival_rate:Optional[float] = None

        def helper(driver:WebDriver)->Optional[str]:
            """
            Parse it:

            <fin-streamer class="livePrice yf-mgkamr" data-symbol="TRY=X" data-testid="qsp-price" data-field="regularMarketPrice" data-trend="none" data-pricehint="4" data-value="32.9042" active=""><span>32.9042</span></fin-streamer>
            """

            logger.debug('grab url')
            driver.get(_url) # TODO params, headers, auth       
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")            # get the whole page; you don't need this
            logger.debug('loaded page %s', _url)

            _price = find_element(driver, None, # don't need to make it think we're not a bot, so no wait time
                (By.XPATH, "//fin-streamer[@data-symbol='TRY=X']"), # any one of these *should* work
                (By.XPATH, "//fin-streamer[@data-testid='qsp-price']"), # the other script uses an LLM to generate these
                (By.XPATH, "//fin-streamer[@data-field='regularMarketPrice']"), # that's too big and expensive to be useful
                fallback=None) # fallback is used to press 'enter' when clicking 'next' fails. don't worry about it
            return _price.get_attribute('data-value')
        try:
            async with selenium_async.use_browser(options=options, pool=pool) as driver:
                result:Optional[str] = await asyncio.to_thread(helper, driver)
                await logger.ainfo('result: %s', result)
        except AttributeError as error:
            logger.error(error)
        return result

It's not pretty, but it returns what you want.
2024-07-27 17:11:01 [debug    ] grab url                      
2024-07-27 17:11:05 [debug    ] loaded page https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TRY=X/
2024-07-27 17:11:05 [debug    ] find_element                  
2024-07-27 17:11:05 [debug    ] searching xpath //fin-streamer[@data-symbol='TRY=X']
2024-07-27 17:11:06 [info     ] result: 32.9042               
2024-07-27 17:11:06 [error    ] 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_blank'


Few things I noticed

check if this html tag exist "class": "container yf-mgkamr" exist.

This code below might be the problem perhaps you are accessing an index that does not exist
dolar = soup.find("div", {"class": "container yf-mgkamr"}).find_all("span")[0].text

The website might have kicked you out.


